# TabHost.setOnTabChangedListener not working in Nougat

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using the following code for tab activity`

```
   public class ControlTab_Activity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener
{
public static TabHost mTabHst;

Intent myintent=getIntent();
        int val=myintent.getIntExtra("FromLogout", 0);
        //  if(BaseActivity.gmailactivityflag == 0)
            Resources res = getResources();
            //      try
            //      {
            intent1= new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
            intent2 = new Intent(this,MyCartActivity.class);
            intent3 = new Intent(this,ReorderActivity.class);
            intent4 = new Intent(this,TrackActivity.class);
            intent5 = new Intent(this,MyAccountActivity.class);
            intent5.putExtra("FromLogout", val);
            mTabHst = getTabHost();

            mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("Home")
                    .setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_home_tab))
                    .setContent(intent1));

            mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("My Cart")
                    .setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_cart_tab))
                    .setContent(intent2));

            mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("Reorder")
                    .setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_recorder_tab))
                    .setContent(intent3));

            mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("Track")
                    .setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_track_tab))
                    .setContent(intent4));


            mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("My Account")
                    .setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_account_tab))
                    .setContent(intent5));

            mTabHst.setOnTabChangedListener((OnTabChangeListener) this);

}
```

`
The above code is working fine till Marshmello but the onTabChange method of SetOnTabChangeListener does not get call when code is run on Nougat.I am not getting what is the problem